# Train neural net on another computer?

Tags: machine-learning

I have a complex neural net that will take forever on my laptop to train and i dont have a computer with a GPU, is there a way to run a python script on another computer without having to install an IDE on that computer? (for instance, if i went to an internet cafe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't require an IDE. You just need to install the Python interpreter to run a Python program.

Running machine learning on another computer is in fact industry standard. Google, Amazon and Azure can provide you a virtual machine, which you can run anything you want.

I personally rent a powerful machine with GPUs on Google to do my machine learning analysis. It's not free but very powerful.

Comment: is it cheaper to go through google or to run it at an internet cafe?

Comment: @MarkMarkrowaveCharlton You can't do machine learning in an internet cafe. Why not just spend the Internet Cafe money on renting a cloud machine?

Comment: ok i will look into it